# How to create a custom path in URL using nodeJS/expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, routes

I'd like to be able to create a custom path. for example, if a user clicks a button [create room], the browser redirects the user to: http://www.example.com/[room_id]/index.html

Is there anyway to implement this? The user would be submitting a form, with a button. something along those lines.

basically here is what i have

index.html

```
<form method='POST' name='path_id' id='clickedButtom'>

    <input id="pickName" class="center-align" type='text'>
    <input id='rea2dy' value=" Ready >" type='submit'>      

</form>
```

server.js

```
app.get('path_id', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hello');
});
//I was the path_id to be a random string of letters and numbers basically
```

Comment: If there is a back end server handling the form, it can be done by redirecting the users to your desired URL

Comment: Im not sure i understand, i updated the question to provide more insight

Comment: What I meant was that at the back end you can do `res.redirect('http://your.site/custom/path')`

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For all the URLs you're talking about, you can define a single Express route in advance like this that will have code inside the route to look at the room id and act accordingly:

```
app.post('/createRoom, (req, res) => {
     // do whatever you do here to create the room data structure on the server
    // and assign it an ID
    let roomID = ...;
    res.redirect(`/${roomID}/index.html`);
});

app.get('/:roomID/index.html', (req, res) => {
    let roomID = req.params.roomID;
    // now render whatever you want the user to see for this particular room
    res.send(...);
});
```

Comment: @pylot - Does this answer your question?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and also earn yourself some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.